# How to derive Such infinite sum representation for Hypergeometric function?

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I was reading a paper $[1]$ in which authors claimed that we can simplify below Gauss function to finite series if $m $ and $v$ are positive integers.

$$ _2F_{1}(v,m+v;m+1;x)=\psi\sum_{c=0}^{v-1} {v+m-1\choose c}{2v-2-c\choose v-1} \gamma^c$$

for values of $\psi$ and the$\gamma$ include x values as beow:

$$\gamma = \frac{1-x}{x}$$

However, I know $[2]$ the Hyper geometric, $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;z;x)$,function terminates if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is non-positive integers. This bothers me how such positive arguments can lead to a finite series representation.

Thanks

---

**References**:

[1]    https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1247815

[2]    Table of Integrals, Series and Products, I.S, Gradshteyn, et. al., 2007.

Comment: Exploit the hypergeometric differential equation and prove that the LHS is some polynomial multiplied by $(1-z)^{2\nu+1}$. After that, compute the coefficients of such polynomial.

Comment: Moreover, the LHS has no singularity in the origin, and a pole of order $2\nu+1$ in $z=1$, so $\gamma$ has to be $\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Comment: Note: $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;z;x)$ terminates (i.e. is a polynomial) if $\alpha$ **or** $\beta$ are **non-positive** integers.

Comment: (+1) Are you suggesting that start with $z(1-z){\ddot{u}} + (\lambda-(\alpha+\beta+1)z){\dot{u}}-\alpha\beta u=0$ and show this equation can wirtten as sum of elements similar to below:
$$ \frac{k_1}{z^2} + \frac{k_2}{z(z-1)}+ \frac{k_3}{(z-1)^2}$$

Comment: @gammatester it was typo thanks

Comment: @Jack, why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: long story. I already answered this question and had a bit of a fight with the OP because what I wrote was not understood. I deleted my answer, then the OP deleted his question and re-posted it essentially unchanged. So I prefer just to leave some comment.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Although he answered the question, but his answer was essentially the current comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at DLMF 15.8.1 you will see that:
$F\left(\begin{array}{c}
a,b\\
c
\end{array};z\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{a}}F\left(\begin{array}{c}
a,c-b\\
c
\end{array};\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$
Now in your case $b=m+v,c=m+1$
So $c-b=m+1-m-v=1-v$
and if $v\in\mathcal{N}$
  $-v$ is a negative integer.